# Add parameters to a web widget

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a simple web-widget similar to Facebook Like button, and I want to set some parameters(ex. websiteId) to use them in my dynamically added script(http://analytics.dev/bundles/andreistatistics/js/like-button.js).

My question is: is there a way to pass my param **websiteId** to use it in like-button.js file? I would also like to avoid conflicts with other wbesiteId params defined in DOM.

```
        <div class="like-button-container"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var websiteId = 7;

                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id))
                    return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "http://analytics.dev/bundles/andreistatistics/js/like-button.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'my-like-button'));
        </script>
```

Comment: The easiest would be to add it as a GET (query string) parameter to the `.src` of the script itself - that'd isolate it completely and let you handle it on the server side. That's kind of subjective though and it really depends on a more specific use case.

Comment: And how would I get that value from the query string to use it in my file?

Comment: Actually I found a useful article here http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html